# como hago suma y resta en el view o en el modelo django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

tengo 6 campos 2 seran consultados de 1 tabla, o sea que seran fijo dependiendo de loq eu tenga disponible el usuario y los otros 4, 2 contendran el valor ingresado por el usuario y los 2 el resultado, de la resta o suma dependiendo de la opcion que elija el usuario "adicionar" seria sumar o "disponer", seria sumar, solo me basta un ejemplo para saber la sintaxis por favor como seria o la formas mas comoda, ya sea en el model.py o en el view.py por favor

```
models.py
class Peticiones(models.Model):
solit_choices = (
    ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
    ('Disponer','Disponer'),
)
solicitudes_ids = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
usuario = models.ForeignKey(LocalUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
blank=True)
peticion = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, 
null=True, blank=True)
fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
razon = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
dias_diponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
horas_disponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
total_d = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
total_h = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Puedes agregar [expresiones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/) y el query quedaria algo como :   `from django.db.models import Sum, F
Peticiones.objects.filter(<tu_filtro>).aggregate(Sum(F('campo_1')*F('campo2'))) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por convenio de buenas prácticas tu modelo `Practicas` se debería de llamar `Practica`. Las clases deberían de estar definidas en singular.

Respecto a tu duda, la manera óptima de hacer lo que pretendes es usando la expresión [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). Por ejemplo en `views.py`:

```
Reportes.objects.filter(pk=1).update(total_d=F('total_d') + F('total_h'))
```

Se utiliza `filter` más `update` para ahorrarte una query respecto a `get` más `save`.

Si es una operación que vas a realizar continuamente y desde distintos sitios quizás te convenga crear un atributo en `models.py` para el modelo `Peticiones` por comodidad aunque sea menos óptimo:

```
class Peticiones(models.Model):
    total_d = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_h = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.total_d + self.total_h
```

`get_total` puedes usarlo como un atributo más de tu modelo.

Comment: Buen dia, uno de los campos a sumar y a restar estan en otra clase "UserLocal", que no agregue en el comentario, pregunta: si el campo esta en otra tabla del models.py, igual puedo crear el atributo con la sintaxis, que mencionas alli?
        def get_total_d(self):
            form_1 = ['Adicionar']
            if form.is_valid():
                return self.dias_diponer + self.d_pendientes
                total_d = property(get_total_d)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo lo que quieres es mostrar la suma de dos campos de tu modelo Peticiones:

```
 solicitudes_ids = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 usuario = models.ForeignKey(LocalUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
 null=True, 
 blank=True)
 peticion = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, 
 null=True, blank=True)
 fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 razon = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
 periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
 periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
 dias_diponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
 horas_disponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
 total_d = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
 total_h = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

 def _get_total(self):
    return self.campo_de_modelo+self.otro_Campo_del_modelo

total = property(_get_total)
```

Y ya en tu vista puede acceder a el como un campo mas del modelo

Comment: el total = property(_get_total) se le puede asignar a otro campo?

Comment: total es tu campo, solo cambia eso por el nombre del campo que quieres

Comment: Buenas trades, los estoy haciendo asi:
        def get_h_pendientes(self):
        return self.horas_adicion + self.h_pendientes
        h_pendientes = property(get_h_pendientes)

Pero cuando meto los valores en el formulario en esos mismos campos, no sucede nada, ayuda por favor